# SQL Server - Schrödinger's View

Tags: sql-server

I can't create/alter a VIEW because it already exists.
I also can't drop the same VIEW because it does not exists!

First of all, I'm **SA** on a SQL Server 2012.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[some_name]
```

> There is already an object named 'some_name' in the database.

`DROP VIEW [dbo].[some_name]`

> Cannot drop the view 'dbo.some_name', because it does not exist or you
> do not have permission.

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.some_name', N'V')
SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.some_name', 'V')
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.some_name')
SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.some_name')
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'some_name')
SELECT OBJECT_ID('some_name')
```

NULL (for each query)

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE '%some_name%'
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name ='some_name'
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = N'some_name'
```

empty result (for each query)

```
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(N'dbo.some_name','OBJECT')
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('dbo.some_name','OBJECT')
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(N'some_name','OBJECT')
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('some_name','OBJECT')
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(N'some_name','VIEW')
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('some_name','VIEW')
```

empty result (for each query)

Alt+F1 on 'some_name':

> The object 'some_name' does not exist in database 'X' or is invalid
> for this operation.

```
EXEC sp_rename 
@objname = 'other_name',
@newname = 'some_name'
```

> Error: The new name 'some_name' is already in use as a object name and
> would cause a duplicate that is not permitted.

```
EXEC sp_rename 
@objname = 'some_name',
@newname = 'other_name'
```

> No item by the name of 'some_name' could be found in the current
> database 'X', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.

And now something interesting. If I run:

```
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[some_name]
DROP SYNONYM [dbo].[some_name] 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[some_name]
DROP TRIGER[dbo].[some_name]
DROP TYPE [dbo].[some_name]
DROP VIEW [dbo].[some_name]
```

I get **only 5** messages:

> Cannot drop the [FUNCTION, SYNONYM, TABLE, TRIGGER, TYPE]
> 'dbo.some_name', because it does not exist or you do not have
> permission. (no mention of the VIEW)

But if I move the View command to the top :

```
DROP VIEW [dbo].[some_name]
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[some_name]
DROP SYNONYM [dbo].[some_name] 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[some_name]
DROP TRIGER[dbo].[some_name]
DROP TYPE [dbo].[some_name]
```

I get **6 messages**, as expected.

Please help.

**UPDATE**

After a few CHECKDB commands I found what seems to be the problem. As suspected, this view is in an unconsistend state. By the DBCC command log I got the object_id of it. It does not existis on sys.objects, but it does existis on sys.columns. So, there are a few orphan columns on my database, which indicates a failure when creating or dropping this object.

So, by running DBCC CHECKCATALOG (and a few other DBCC commands) I got the messages:

> Msg 3853, State 1: Attribute
> (referenced_major_id=859202161,referenced_minor_id=42) of row
> (class=0,object_id=990678627,column_id=0,referenced_major_id=859202161,referenced_minor_id=42)
> in sys.sql_dependencies does not have a matching row
> (object_id=859202161,column_id=42) in sys.columns.

> Msg 8956, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Index row (1:123:12) with values
> (nsclass = 0 and nsid = 1 and name = 'some_name') points to the data
> row identified by (RID = (1:456:45)).

**SOLUTION**

0 - Backup your database.

1 - Reboot your server on Single User Mode (-m parameter)

2 - Set the database to Single User Mode:

```
ALTER DATABASE X
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
```

3 - Run a CHECKDB command with a repair option. In my case it was:

```
DBCC CHECKDB (X,REPAIR_REBUILD)
```

4 - Set the database back to Multi User Mode

```
ALTER DATABASE X
SET MULTI_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
```

'X' is the name of the database.
I'm not sure if step 0 and 1 are really necessary, but better safe than sorry.

You may find more info about the CHECKDB command and its repair otions at: [DBCC CHECKDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I suspect that the object `some_name` isn't a `VIEW`, it's something else, and hence why you didn't find it with `SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.some_name', N'V')`. Why put wild cards around it when you searched `sys.objects`? `SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = N'some_name'` is what you want.

Comment: @Larnu SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.some_name') and OBJECT_ID('dbo.some_name') and OBJECT_ID('some_name') all gives a NULL result.
I'll try your query, but I don't see the problem with LIKE here.

Comment: UPDATE: Yep, same thing, an empty result.

Comment: @Larnu Would it help if I start the server using the Single-User Mode?

Comment: Very unlikely to, @Pedro . We really need an [mre] here as I suspect we're msising something trivial here.

Comment: @Larnu, I cannot supply a minimal reproducible example since I'm able to create every object on this database. Tables, Views, Triggers, you name it. This error occurs only for this specific object (name) that I just can't find.

Answer (score 0):

I think SQL server requires that object names be unique. You certainly cannot have a table and a view with the same name, as it would be impossible to distinguish which object was intended when you refer to it. But I think function and procedure names also have to be unique ( and this may not be strictly necessary, as far as I know the context in which these names are used always allows them to be distinguished ).

Comment: *"I think SQL server requires that object names be unique"* there's no "think" about it, object names must be unique (as determined by the database's collation) within the schema they are defined in.

Answer (score 0):

From your error messages, I understand that `dbo.some_name` exists, but, you don't have enough permissions to view dbo.some_name.

`sys.objects` will show only the objects, to which you have got permission to view .[MSDN reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Permissions
>
> The visibility of the metadata in catalog views is limited
>   to securables that a user either owns or on which the user has been
>   granted some permission.

You can see what permissions you have got on an object by running the below query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('dbo.some_name','OBJECT')
```

You need to have CONTROL permission to drop it. You need to have ALTER permission to rename the object.

**UPDATE**

can you please again check whether you are part of sysadmin role at server level and part of db_owner role at db level (sysadmins enter database as db_owners).

```sql
use database_name
go
SELECT Is_srvrolemember('sysadmin')
select IS_ROLEMEMBER('db_owner')
```

Comment: The OP does lead with saying they are a `sysadmin`, which means they would have "all of the permissions" and any explicit `DENY` would be ignored.

Comment: As mentioned, I'm using the SA login. Also, I'm the only one who knows the SA password.
Is it even possible that a non SA user have changed permissions in a way that the SA is not allowed to access a given object?

Comment: Your query using fn_my_permissions() results on an empty dataset.
As I said, I'm SA. It should eliminate any permission issue.

Comment: @Pedro, I have updated my answer. Can you please check again for your permissions

Comment: @VenkataramanR, I got the result 1 for each query. The problem here is about consistency of the database's metadata, not permission. Thanks for the effort.